# Path completion for gEdit

Tags: gedit

Is there any gedit plugin for path completion?
or there is already implemented without any need to install completion?

Comment: What do you mean? (a) When you are opening or saving a file? ...OR... (b) While you are typing inside the editor, you would like it to detect that you are typing a path and offer suggestions or completions?

Comment: I meant (b): when typing a path. For word/code completion, it is already there, but for path completion.